# Convert this relative path to absolute

Tags: ajax

In the .js script below, the ajaxPath reference breaks when the containing page is off the root directory of the site. Is there a workaround to make this path absolute?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    initContentEditable();

    var dir = ContentEditableSettings.content_editable_url;
    var ajaxPath = 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'; //THIS RELATIVE PATH BREAKS OUTSIDE ROOT DIRECTORY

    function initContentEditable(){                 
        $('.contenteditable.furniture').blur(updateContentEditable);
        $('.contenteditable.custom').blur(updateContentEditableCustom);
        $('.contenteditable.title').blur(updateContentEditableTitle);
        $('.contenteditable').each(function(){
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            var display = parent.css('display');
            $(this).css('display', display);
        });
    }   

    function updateContentEditableTitle(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var span = $(this);
        var data = new Object();
        data.pid = span.attr('data-pid');
        data.title = span.find('.saver').text();
        data.action = 'ce_update_title';
        data.security = ContentEditableSettings.nonce;
        $.post(ajaxPath, data, onContentSaved); //AJAXPATH BREAKS AS RELATIVE REF
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your `wp-admin` directory is still at the root of your site, you can just add a forward slash (`/`) to the URI. Alterntaively, you can use [`wp_localize_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to pass in your site's URL or, if you are using WordPress's AJAX functions, the `ajaxurl` JS variable.

```
var ajaxPath = '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
```

Or

```
<?php
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
$translation_array = array( 'ajaxPath' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );
?>
```

Comment: Use admin_url instead of site_url. Like this: `wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );`

Comment: Thanks, @Otto! I was rolling that off the top of my head and forgot about `admin_url()`.